# How do I use conditional formatting on one column based on certain characters in another column?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

When column `D` has a hyphen (`-`) in it, I want the fill color in column `H` to change.
What is the custom formula for that?

Answer (score 2):

Please place the following formula in cell `H1`:

```
=SEARCH("-",$D1)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well. If not, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.