# Help making a formula that will conditionally extract digits?

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P4jCgHfb8tiQ3vXEP9TfuAPaE8ygLDHFu7meQ-taUJY/edit?usp=drivesdk

I want to try to make a formula that will read what is on Main2, read if it has the specific text in it, then extract the number. And add those numbers together.

Do I need to use REGEXREPLACE? I've never heard of that and I'm having trouble learning it.

So for the example in there, I want it to scan everything on Main2 and see if it has the words "Chuchu Jelly" in it. If it does then I want it to extract the digits and then add all the digits up. The adding them up part doesn't sound complicated but I don't know how to do the rest.

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: @marikamitsos The OP shared the spreadsheet few minutes ago.

Comment: Thank you @Rubén for the heads up. Looking at OP's sheet though, it looks like the problem is solved.

Comment: @marikamitsos It is solved but it won't let me delete it. Someone on Reddit helped me a few minutes after I posted it and now I'm not allowed to delete it.

Comment: Just make a copy of it then. *"Reddit can be a nasty place :)"*

Comment: BTW, Why won't you accept [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/136804/117311)?